# How to add space between label and input and make input go to right edge of container in same line?

Tags: html, css

I'm completely new at html/CSS and I can't seem to be able to find how to both add spacing between labels and input while making the input extend to the right edge of it's enclosing container and have both the label and input be on the same line.

so far I have:

```css
label {
 text-align: right;
 clear: both;
 float:left;
 margin-right:25px;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <form action="home.html">
    <label for="label">Label:</label>
    <input type="text" id="rcorners1" name="field_name">
 <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
 </form>
</div>
```

This makes the label appear above the input which makes sense because I set the width to 100%. What is a good solution? I do not want to set the width to a specific pixel size, but rather have the width always extend from the label to the right edge of the container no matter the size of the label itself.

I understand similar questions may have been asked before but I can't find a solution so thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
label {
 text-align: right;
 float:left;
 margin-right:25px;
 width:100px;
}
input {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  float:left;
}
```

with your HTML

```
<label for="label">Label:</label>
<input type="text" id="rcorners1" name="field_name">
```

See it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/site2goal/vq4tdf1k/3/)

Note: you can set the with of the label as you like

Comment: Thank you! calculating the width with respect to the label worked perfectly.

Comment: @leedex Glad it helps. Clearly you can play with it to suit your needs